# Overloading operators in C++ arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I'm relatively new to C++, thus the question. I'm trying to overload () operator for read and write operations in an array. This is a row-major array which maps a two -dimensional array to a one dimension.

This is the overload that I've written for read operations

```
//overloading read operator
    const double& operator()const(int n, int m){
      return arr_[n*column+m];
    }
```

Now I need to write a write overload that inserts a double value in the position returned by the read overload.

```
//overloading write operator
    double& operator()(double d){

    }
```

How exactly can I do that. Any help appreciated.

Comment: "...inserts a double value in that position" What position? Your write operator defines only a double value, not a position.

Comment: @zenith in the position returned by the read overload

Comment: Do exactly the same, but remove the `consts` and you can say `data(x,y) = 0;`.

Comment: @molbdnilo but the row  and column is not defined in the write overload. I'm not getting the correct signature.

Comment: BTW, you've placed the `const` in the wrong place in your existing code, member modifiers (*cv-qualifier-seq*) go after the argument list.

Answer (score 5):

The overload itself wouldn't insert anything; it would return a (non-`const`) reference which you can use to assign to an array element. The overload would be the same as your `const` overload (which you still need in addition to this one, to access constant objects), but without any `const`:

```
double& operator()(int n, int m){
  return arr_[n*column+m];
}
```

used thusly

```
array(2,3) = 42;
```